# Proof verification: Metrizable spaces are completely regular.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, separation-axioms

Let X be a metrizable space with metric $d$. For disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ there is a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$ such that $f(A)=\{0\}$ and $f(B) = \{1\}$. Hence by the Urysohn lemma, for each $x_0\in X\setminus A$ where $A$ is a closed set, there exists a continuous function $g:X\to[0,1]$ with $g(x_0) = 1$ and $g(A) = \{0\}$, so that $X$ is completely regular.

Is this correct?

Comment: We do not need Urysohn's Lemma here. The function $f$ applies if $B=\{x_0\}$ since one-member subsets (singletons) are closed in metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in a metrisable space all one-point sets *are* closed. You don't have to name it as a precondition.

Secondly, if you are already applying Urysohn's lemma, you know that $X$ is normal and normal (plus $T_1$) implying completely regular is trivial, and well-known.

A direct proof of completete regularity: If $x \notin A$ and $A$ is closed,
then $f(y)=d(y,x)$ is continuous, maps $x$ to $0$ and all $y \in A$ to a value $\ge d(x,A) > 0$, (positive as $A$ is closed). So rescaling (by dividing by $d(x,A)$, say, and truncating the value to $1$) will give a continuous map to $[0,1]$ that separates $x$ and $A$.

It's a sort of warm up for making Urysohn functions like your $f$.

So your proof as it stands I would not accept, I think.

Comment: The point of the exercise was to prove this statement using the Urysohn lemma.

Comment: @Math1000 Then just say: apply Urysohn's lemma to $A$ and $B=\{x_0\}$, which is always closed in a metric space. Done. No need for a formula or anything.

Comment: Well, I also wanted to prove Urysohn lemma for metrizable spaces, so the proof would be self-contained.

Comment: @Math1000 You cannot keep doing that. Just rely on results that are proven earlier. Reproofs are not needed.

Comment: Not needed, but perhaps a good exercise?